# Removing recurring rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of a voting poll, with columns "Timestamp", "Email address", and "Idea". I have to limit each email address's voting count to maximum 3 per day. The dataframe looks like this (with a lot more votes from different email addresses)

```
Timestamp          Email address   Idea
5/26/2021 17:28:44 abc@gmail.com   a
5/26/2021 17:28:49 abc@gmail.com   b 
5/26/2021 17:28:51 abc@gmail.com   c 
5/26/2021 17:29:05 abc@gmail.com   d
5/27/2021 12:01:57 abc@gmail.com   a
```

So I would need to delete the row voting for idea "d". I tried doing df.groupby(['Timestamp', 'Email address']).head(3), but that wouldn't make sense since it is also taking the time of the vote into account. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Does creating a date column then grouping them by three work? That eliminates the issue with all/most time stamps being unique.

```py
df[‘date’] = df[‘Timestamp’].dt.date()

df.groupby(['date', 'Email address']).head(3)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to assign the created column into the df. You could just store it as a series and use it in groupby.

Comment: I get the AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.

Comment: What do you get when you do `df[‘Timestamp’].dtype`?